# Analyzing timer job performance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Good morning, I have a SharePoint farm with 3 servers and since last week I have been noticing an issue. Any job executed on server 2 is veeeery slow (it takes more or less 10m to change the status of the jobs, even restarting sptimerv4 it takes the same time to change the status from paused to running) while any jobs executed on the other servers are showing in real time. What can I do debug the timer job on server 2 to find the cause of this slowness?

Answer (score 0):

1.Check SharePoint ULS logs at the same time.

2.Check Event viewer that will also provide some clues.

Answer (score 0):

ETW tracing is going to provide you the most detailed analysis possible as you'll be able to see the amount of CPU time, etc. spent in specific functions.

[PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) would be the recommended tool provided other out of the box diagnostic logging fail to provide any insights. I would be looking at owstimer.exe and if you know the specific timer job and how it functions, possibly w3wp.exe (for any Web or Service Application it functions against).